# Python - How to 'set' an argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, menubar

I'm working hard to solve this problem, can someone help me ?
There is what I mean by 'set' an argument:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
I=1
def add():
    global I
    menu1.add_command(label=I, command=lambda:Text(I))
    I=I+1

def Text(I):
    print(I)
menubar = Menu(window)

menu1 = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menu1.add_command(label="Add", command=add)
menu1.add_separator()
menu1.add_command(label="Quit", command=window.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Files", menu=menu1)

window.config(menu=menubar)

window.mainloop()
```

I want when we click on add and after on '1' it print '1', and when we add '2' and click on it, it print '2' but it always print the value of I, how can I set the argument by

```
menu1.add_command(label=I, command=lambda:Text(1))
```

for exemple ?
I don't know if I'm clear but I don't know how explain it !

Comment: Can you try to show a simpler example? To me the question isn't clear.

Comment: So, you want each button on the menu to remember what the value of `I` was when it was created?

Comment: Exactly, thank you, I did not know how to formulate it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `Text` function to be a [closure](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Closures):

```
def Text(I):
    def inner():
        print(I)
    return inner
```

Then change your `add` function to be this:

```
def add():
    global I
    text = Text(I)
    menu1.add_command(label=I, command=text)
    I=I+1
```

This will save the `I` in the `text` variable. The `text` variable is actually a function, `inner`, that will print `I` when called.

Or you could make your closure inline if you wanted to use the `Text` function somewhere else:

```
import functools
...    
menu1.add_command(label=I, command=functools.partial(Text, i))
```

Comment: You can make a closure on the fly with `functools.partial`; in this case: `menu1.add_command(label=I, command=partial(Text, i))`

Comment: @Jonathan Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

I think your problem is the `lambda:Text(I)`. In this case, you have created a closure, but the closure knows I to be a global and is evaluating it at a later date.

You probably want to immediately evaluate `Text(I)` and use that as your result:

```
texti = Text(I)   # Immediate evaluation
menu1.add_command(label=I, command=lambda:texti)  # Return prior value of "I"
```

Comment: This does not work; it prints it immediately and not when they click it.